# How can make annotation in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, reflection, annotations

I have seen annotation in Spring framework. And I wonder how can I make annotation.

We have used many annotation(eg. @Controller, @Autowired, @RequestMapping and so on). Using such annotation, We do NOT code with reflection. But I cannot find tutorial for making annotation without reflection. In all tutorials, writers demonstrate annotation with reflection.

If I don't use reflection, CANNOT I make annotation?

Comment: The question is an annotation to do what? (your question might be an X/Y problem)

Comment: @RC. Thank you for your concerning. When I use spring's annotation, I don't need to use reflection. But When I use customer's annotation, I have to use reflection. What Is the difference?

Comment: @blank_popup Because the annotations were made by the Spring developers, they've also made the code that handles the annotation (through reflection or bytecode weaving). For example the `@Transactional` annotation is handled by `org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor`.

Comment: @Kayaman Thank you for your concerning. I will consult spring's source.

Comment: @blank_popup I can save you some time. The interceptor is called from a Java `Proxy` through reflection. Bytecode weaving using `AspectJ` for example can be used too, but in the end it's pretty much the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can *make* an annotation without using reflection.
You just won't be able to use it for anything. An annotation itself has no logic, it's just a marker that depends on code that will see the annotation and then perform some action. The easiest way to demonstrate that kind of code is with reflection.

Comment: An annotation can have logic.

Comment: @PeterRader Care to elaborate on that? Show me a custom made annotation that will do something without having other code use reflection to check that the annotation exists.

Comment: Sorry no code, i answer in train using handy. Well you can subclass a enum and create a constructor for a value used as default-value. In the constructor you write `System.out.println("me exists")`

Comment: This question is about annotations, not enums.

Comment: @PeterRader Also, you cannot extend enums in Java - they're final.

Comment: @Kayaman I did not say your answer is wrong, but that a annotation can have no logic is wrong.

Comment: @kryger Subclass != extend. Or what do you mean?

Comment: @PeterRader Well, your answer is wrong. Annotations can't have logic, it's just metadata. If you can show me an annotation with logic, or an `enum` extending another `enum`, I'll give you a prize.

Comment: @PeterRader So far you haven't contributed anything useful to this question. Your annotation answer was wrong, then you for some reason brought up enums and managed to claim incorrectly that you can extend enums. Either prove my answer incorrect or be quiet.

Comment: @Kayaman what exactly is wrong in my answer to the op's question?

Comment: @PeterRader Well, seems I was wrong about the "your answer was wrong" part (possibly because it seems like it was written by a drunk in the pub). Anyhow, when you get to a computer, please check your facts.

Comment: Thank you! I am a newbie for spring framework. Seeing your replying, I recalled enum, extend and annotation and reviewed. I think that I get many things about java.

Answer (score 0):

You can write Annotations from JDK5 and better. But only reflection (xand the static-scope) can read Annotations!

Annotations was a alternate to xdoclet-tags, they was part of Javadoc so your question is like "can i write documentation" - well yes.

There is a joke about Memory that only can be written but not be read, the [WOM(write-only-memory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-only_memory_(joke)).

If **you** do not like to use Reflection, a 3rd party library can read Annotations via reflection for you.

What you can do is to Annotate your Annotations.

Example:

```
@Autowired(required=false)
private MyService service;
```

Can be shorten by a custom annotation like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Autowired(required=false)
public @interface MyOptional {
}
```

Now you can change the code to

```
@MyOptional
private MyService service;
```

You see, you can use custom annotations without reflection-code.

Comment: Thank you for your cencerning. I found out many things because of you!.